# Setting up the thumbnail link for social media websites on SharePoint

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, image, rollup-image

When users of our websites share a link from our SharePoint website on Facebook, Yammer, or any other social media, the image thumbnail defaults to a random image (see image) [image: Image of shared link from SharePoint]

We've attempted to add an image under the Page Settings > Edit Properties > Page Image, but it did not successfully display an image.

We are looking to have the page image to either display our organization's logo or the feature image for that SharePoint page.

Has anyone been able to do this in SharePoint? If so, what steps should we be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Open Graph tags in the SharePoint 2013 master pages. It's worth looking into Open Graph tags to understand it in more depth if you plan on using more of these tags. Here are two articles that I found useful:

- [What are Open Graph Tags?](https://www.redclayinteractive.com/what-are-open-graph-tags/)
- [Setting Up Social For Success: How To Customize Preview Thumbnail Images For Your Website](https://cypressnorth.com/social-media-advertising/how-to-customize-preview-thumbnail-images-for-pages-on-your-website/)

In the end, my master page code had two additional metatags as follows:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/Style%20Library/YOUR-IMAGE-THUMBNAIL.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
```

Just be aware that this sets the thumbnail image for ALL links that are derived from your website.